# Why does Ansible fail to execute this simple shell script?

Tags: string, bash, shell, solaris, ansible

I came across a very strange problem with Ansible (1.8.2) that boils down to executing this simple command in a shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

# transform a String into lowercase chars:
echo "TeSt" | tr [:upper:] [:lower:]
```

When I log into the remote Solaris machine, this script seems to work no matter in which shell I am (e.g., `/bin/sh`, `/bin/bash`):

```
# ./test.sh 
test
```

Also when I execute this script using a remote ssh command, it works:

```
# ssh root@<remote-host> '/tmp/test.sh'
test
```

However, when I execute the same script with the Ansible `command` or `shell` modules, I get a "Bad String" error no matter what shell I specify:

```
- shell: executable=/bin/sh /tmp/test.sh      [FATAL stderr: Bad string]
- shell: executable=/bin/bash /tmp/test.sh    [FATAL stderr: Bad string]
- command: /tmp/test.sh                       [FATAL stderr: Bad string]
```

It took me ages to figure out that it works with the `raw` module:

```
- raw: executable=/bin/sh /tmp/test.sh        [OK]
```

Does anyone have a clue why the `shell` and `command` modules produce this error?

Some more info about the remote host on which the script fails:

- SunOS 5.10 Generic_150401-18 i86pc i386 i86pc
- All shells (`/bin/sh`, `/bin/bash`, `/bin/ksh`) are GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
- Python 2.6.6

The locale differs! When I log in or execute a remote ssh command, the locale looks like this:

```
LANG=
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_ALL=
```

However, with Ansible, I get this:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Does quoting the arguments to `tr` help? What sort of system is this running on? What is the locale?

Comment: I added some system information. Quoting the arguments to `tr` is not an option, the script is part of a package installation and I cannot modify that code.

Comment: @dokaspar Then it is time for a bug report to whoever wrote that broken script.

Comment: @Jens: yes, I will certainly do that!

Comment: Can you replace the tr script for another script ignoring the arguments and just executing `tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`. Or when you do not want to change the tr, change your PATH before executing the package installation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay.  So, despite what Jens says, that script is not "broken" in most environments.  I tested it as written under `bash`, `bash --posix`, `dash`, `busybox sh`, and `ksh` from the `pdksh` package, and in all cases it works.

So I went searching for that specific error message (`Bad string`), and found:

http://sourceforge.net/p/wrapper/bugs/229/

Which appears to exactly describe your problem.  It's not a bug in the script; it's a bug in `tr` on Solaris.

Comment: The script _is_ broken: the `[:upper:]` and `[:lower:]` _must be quoted!_ That's because `[...]` are going to be understood by the shell as a character range. Try it from within a folder that contains, e.g., the file named `u`. You'll see that (unquoted) `[:upper:]` will expand as `u`. It's not because it _seems_ to work most of the times that it _does_ work every time. @Jens explains this very well in his answer.

Comment: Yup, my comment about quoting came from finding similar information about "broken" `/bin/tr` on Solaris.

Comment: The script is broken and no amount of handwaving is going to change it. If a one character file named `u` is in the CWD of the script, the `tr` is translating u to u, effectively doing nothing. If there are **two** one character files, say `e` and `r` it will run `tr e r e r` which fails with an error. It might not be your error, but it's a time bomb waiting to explode.

Comment: Regardless, quoting is not the issue behind the error.  Maybe the OP can open a new question if he encounters problems caused by erroneous shell expansion.

Comment: I start to get the feeling that both is true... (1) the script *is* broken because it fails with a file named `u` in the CWD, and (2) there is also a bug in Solaris `tr` because the script still works in any other environments (provided that there is no file named `u`...)

Answer (score 0):

Whatever other problem you have, there's certainly a problem with your `tr` command,

```
tr [:upper:] [:lower:]
```

because `[]` is a character range specification **expanded by the shell**. If by chance you have a file named `:`, `u`, `p`, `e`, `r`, `l`, `o`, or `w` this will get expanded before `tr` sees it as an argument:

```
$ touch u
$ echo [:upper:]
u
```

Fix: use quotes, as in

```
tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'
```

Comment: Who are the two misinformed people downvoting this answer? Not even providing a rationale?

Comment: +1 Thanks for the explanation! Unfortunately, the unquoted arguments lie inside code that I cannot fix myself :(